# Alternating group $\operatorname{Alt}(n)$, $n>4$ has no subgroup of index less than $n$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

I have read somewhere (do know where) the following statement.

> Alternating group $\operatorname{Alt}(n)$, $n>4$ has no subgroup of index less than $n$.

I want to prove it.

If there is a subgroup $H$ of $\operatorname{Alt}(n)$, $n>4$, of inex $d<n$ then the action of $\operatorname{Alt}(n)$ on the set of all left (or right) cosets of $H$ in $\operatorname{Alt}(n)$ gives rise to a nontrivial epimorphism from $\operatorname{Alt}(n)$ to $\operatorname{Alt}(d)$ contradicting the fact that $\operatorname{Alt}(n)$ is simple.

Is this proof correct?? If not, Please suggest a proof.

Comment: Why do you get an epimorphism?

Comment: As poined out by @PrahladVaidyanathan, you need not get an epimorphism. But you do get a non-trivial map, which is enough here.

Comment: @user93432  you might have read it in [this link](http://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/9781848009875-c2.pdf?SGWID=0-0-45-855487-p173841638). You can see its general form in [Topics in Algebra by I.N.Herstein](http://www.math.iisc.ernet.in/~rakesh13/group_theory.pdf‎)