# Does the alternating group $A_5$ contain a subgroup isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_{20}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

What are all the possible orders of elements in the group $A_5$? Does $A_5$ contain a subgroup isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_{20}$? How about $\Bbb Z_{10}$? How about $\Bbb Z_5$? Justify your answers.

---

I've found that the possible orders are 1, 2, 3, and 5. I'm having a hard time conceptualizing this.

The identity in the subgroup must map to the identity in $\Bbb Z_{20}$. There must exist a bijective function from the subgroup to $\Bbb Z_{20}$, and this function must satisfy $f(ab)=f(a)f(b)$.

So I must find a function that works for this? I'm confused.

Comment: See also the [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/580394/alternating-group-operatornamealtn-n4-has-no-subgroup-of-index-less-t)

Answer (score 4):

Hint: a subgroup isomorphic to ${\mathbb Z}_n$ would be generated by an element of order $n$.

Comment: So then the only isomorphism can be to $\Bbb Z_5$?

Answer (score 1):

Another hint:  Any element of $S_n$ can be written as a composition of disjoint cycles.  Further, the order of that composition will be the least common multiple of the length of each cycle within that composition.

Note that a $k$-cycle is an element of $A_5 \iff k$ is odd and $k \leq 5$.

---

Also note that [Cayley's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_theorem%20%22Cayley%27s%20theorem) guarantees that $\mathbb{Z}_5$ is a subgroup of $S_5$.  Would it also be a subgroup of $A_5$?

Comment: So then the only isomorphism can be to ℤ5?

Comment: You said yourself that there are elements of order $1,2$ and $3$ as well as $5$.